# How to disable/enable text field according to a selected value in b-form-select?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

**I'm trying to enable/disable input text field according to values selected in 
b-form-select**

I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: 0,
    options: [
      { value: 0, text: 'Enabled' },
      { value: 1, text: 'Disabled' }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app" class="m-5">
  <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></b-form-select>
  <b-form-input type="text" :disabled="selected === 1" class="mt-3"></b-form-input>
</div>
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nardnob/nkyh1dxs/) for it.